# How do I move from image segmentation to performing operations on my ROI after performing Felzenszwalb segmentation in scikit?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, image-segmentation

In Python, I am using a background removal tool and scikit's Felzenszwalb algorithm to segment my image via

```
from rembg.bg import remove
import numpy as np
import io
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

input_path = 'in.jpg'
output_path = 'out.png'

f = np.fromfile(input_path)
result = remove(f)
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(result)).convert("RGBA")

#importing needed libraries
import skimage.segmentation
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#performing segmentation
res1 = skimage.segmentation.felzenszwalb(img, scale=500)

##uncomment to print results if desired
#fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
#ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
#ax1.imshow(res1); ax1.set_xlabel("k=500")
#fig.suptitle("Graph based image segmentation")
#plt.tight_layout()
```

which gives me a plot of the segmented image in a few different colors. The output `res1` is an ndarray "integer mask indicating segment labels" (from the scikit website). I now want to perform some color analysis on each of these regions. How would I use `res1` to access each mask in turn (with either a homogeneous or transparent background) and perform my color analysis?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Numpy, you can access it with `np.where`

Among the regions you obtained with res1, choose the one you want to analyse (you can list the regions with `np.unique(res1)`). For example for mask '2', do :

```py
masked_img_2 = np.where(res1==2,img,0)
plt.imshow(masked_img_2) # if you want to visualize the result with matplotlib
```

this means : "keep img where res1 is equal to '2', elsewhere set it to Zero"
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html